# How to get the details of user who submitted the spark job from within the job context?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, configuration, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on logging the details of the spark job executions. I would like to get the username of the user who submitted the spark job, from within the context of the spark job.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below command to get the **`spark user`** who submitted the job.

**`Spark >= 2.0`**

```
spark.sparkContext.sparkUser
```

**(or)**

**`spark < 2.0`**

```
sc.sparkUser
```

Comment: please check my Edited answer!